# Set Report Size on Crystal report

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

i am using windows 10.

i am trying to create a report for continuous form (Half Of A4), i set manually from device and printer, so i set printer server like this.

[image]

then i change page setup on CR to `vpc` (name of paper where i create on printer server)  like this..

[image]

then i tried it with different way :

1. i preview the report, than print.

[image]

with out run my application. the print result was great. just like i want.

2. i run my application, preview my report with Crystal REport viewer tools, but my report become landscape. not protrait.

[image]

see...

what must i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, after a week,finally i found the answer, we need to set default paper to our customer paper.

just that.